# Using HashMap with String as key and List as value

Tags: java, hashmap

Right now, I'm learning HashMaps and reading of Excel files.

In my case, I have a folder with several Excel files (5, can be more). In each of those Excel files, I have one ID and 15 columns (Strings, int), so every file has its own ID with different information in the columns.

With a for loop, I read the path with the name and saved it in a list.

Now, I want to map these different id's with the columns. Later, I want to use this information to fill another Excel file where the ID already exists.

Here is my for loop:

```
try {
    int counter = 0;
    String folderPath = "H:\\ExcelFiles";
    File[] files = new File(folderPath).listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " File Number: " + counter);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the method should start like this:

```
private HashMap<String, List> getExcelValues(String fileName) 
        
    HashMap<String, List> excelFiles = new HashMap<>();
```

I really don't know how to write the columns in a list.

Can anyone help out? Maybe with a method that I can use by myself?

Comment: If you want to access data from excel files, you may want toUse CSV files or apache POI.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `List` without specifying the kinds of objects you'll be storing in the `List`, such as `List<Integer>`, `List<String>` or whatever.

Comment: @dan1st later I will read a csv file with content and safe it in a list as well. But for first i want to learn how to work with excel files. But thank you for u tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Working with CSV files would be easy in such cases.
As the CSV files will have the data in a comma-separated format, you can easily ***split the rows by comma (",")*** & extract the respective values, store them in a map & use it as you want.

If you don't want CSV & want a solution for xlx or xlsx files,
You can use the Apache POI library for ease.

```
public class Alex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String folderPath = "H:\\ExcelFiles";
    File[] files = new File(folderPath).listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            InputStream inStream = null;
            try {
                inp = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inStream);

                for(int i=0;i<workbook.getNumberOfSheets();i++) {
                    System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName());
                    readSheet(workbook.getSheetAt(i));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Exception encountered!");}
        }
    }
}

public static void readSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    Row row = null;
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            result.add(row.getCell(j));
        }
    }
    ... add your processing logic ...
}
    
}
```

Comment: My first method was from a type list and it worked good. I had a 2 dimensional arraylist. In the first i read the key and in the second the values. Now, I want to use a HashMap to use it on my file list. Just for the case i need to use it later in my other project with excel files.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention. My Excel list has empty fields between the ID (column A row 8) and columns (start column E row 7). I wanted to take these into account in the method, so that the method only selects rows and columns that are not empty. And stores this information in a HashMap.